# Number of cores available to VMware Player limited to physical cores or hyperthreaded cores?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-player, hyper-threading

I have an i7 with 2 physical cores, because of hyper threading Windows 7 reports 4 cores (at least in the Task Manager). My question is, when allocating cores to a VM in VMWare Player is it taking from the pool of 4 hyper threaded cores or simply 2 physical cores?

Strangely it allows me to select up to 8 cores despite only having 2 physical and 4 total with hyper threading on the host.

So if I say, here Mr.VM take 1 core, will it take 1 of the 4 'cores' or 1 of 2 the physical cores? In the first case I would be giving it 1/2 of my cores, in the second I would be giving it 1/4 of my cores if the hyper threaded cores are included in the pool of available cores.

**Edit**: Here is what the VMWare Player docs say:

Using Virtual Symmetric Multiprocessing

With Virtual Symmetric Multiprocessing (SMP), you can assign up to eight processors to a virtual machine on any host machine that has at least two logical processors.

The following are all considered to have two or more logical processors:

- A multiprocessor host with two or more physical CPUs
- A single-processor host with a multicore CPU
- A single-processor host with hyperthreading enabled

NOTE: On hyperthreaded uniprocessor hosts, performance of virtual machines with Virtual SMP might be
below normal.
With VMware Player you can power on and run multiple dual-processor virtual machines concurrently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In response to your second question:

**So if I say, here Mr.VM take 1 core, will it take 1 of the 4 'cores' or 1 of 2 the physical cores?**

There is an option when you create the VM and also after you have created it, in the settings panel under **Processors** in which you specify whether you want to use both processors, or the cores per processor.

**Edit by Asker:**

> This proves that it does indeed take
>   from a pool of the total cores
>   available that *includes* hyper
>   threaded cores because when I selected
>   8-cores it gave a warning, but when I
>   selected 4-cores it did not.
>
> **The answer: Hyper threaded cores are included in the available cores to be
>   given to the VM.**

[image]

*In my case, I don't have the ability to use that many cores or processors, but with your CPU, you should be able to do so.*

Comment: Ok, this DOES answer my question a bit indirectly. The answer to the question is it chooses from a pool of all 4 cores even though 2 of the 4 are hyper threaded and only 2 physical cores exist. The way I am sure of this now is because if I select '8 cores' it tells me that this is not available, but '4 cores' option is no problem. Thanks for hinting me in the right direction.