# # of Cores in VMWare shows more cores than possible

Tags: cpu, vmware-player

I am trying to help a friend out with a particular issue.. he sent me a screenshot of msinfo32 from a virtual environment he has but the # of cores he is running on seems to be greater than the # of cores the CPU has.

[image]

This screenshot shows he is running on 8 cores but the [Intel Specification page for the X5690](http://ark.intel.com/products/52576/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X5690-12M-Cache-3_46-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI) says it only has 6. How is this possible?

Also, what determines the # of processors that show up in msinfo32?

Comment: Since your CPU is hyperthreaded and has 6 physical cores, it can run 12 concurrent threads, which VMWare sees as the max physical capacity per VM. Note that you can overbook VMWare OSes such that two VMs could think they own all 12 cores each (though you will take a huge performance hit for CPUReady wait).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x5690 is 6C12T due to HT, so its possible to have 8 "logical" cores in VM. Please refer to this question. [Number of cores available to VMware Player limited to physical cores or hyperthreaded cores?](https://superuser.com/questions/276117/number-of-cores-available-to-vmware-player-limited-to-physical-cores-or-hyperthr)